# Plotting Boolean Data and Categories aren't Appearing

Tags: python, matplotlib, boolean

I have a column, `TFColumn` in a Pandas data frame with Boolean values (i.e., TRUE or FALSE). I am trying to plot the number of TRUE and FALSE values using a bar plot.

However, instead of displaying the values TRUE or FALSE on the x-axis under the bars, numeric values are displayed. What can I do to remove the numeric axis and have a categorical axis displayed?

Here is the code I am running for this plot:

```
plt.bar(dat[dat.yr == 2019]['TFColumn'].value_counts().index, dat[dat.yr == 2019]['TFColumn'].value_counts().values)
```

[image]

Comment: Here is [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html) to documentation of plotting categorical variables

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your task could be simpler w/o Pandas:

[image]

```
In [4]: from numpy  import random
   ...: from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots
   ...: random.seed(20221104)
   ...: TFColumn = random.choice((False, True, True), 18000)
   ...: true = sum(TFColumn) ; false = len(TFColumn)-true
   ...: 
   ...: fig, ax = subplots()
   ...: bars = ax.bar((0, 1), (false, true), 0.4)
   ...: ax.set_xticks((0, 1))
   ...: ax.set_xticklabels(('False', 'True'))
   ...: show()
```

Comment: There are other actions I am performing that make me want to continue using Pandas @gboffi

Comment: @324 If other tasks you need to accomplish suggest to use Pandas, you could however elect to use not Pandas for this particular task.